# How do I make an api call in PHP

Tags: php, postman, php-curl

I tested an API using postman. Using, postman, I managed to generate a token.

From postman, I managed to get all the data of a user using the following with the following details via a GET request:

```
https://example.example.co.za/api/consumers/get?id=567675675&email=example@sample.com
```

Under Authorization type, I selected "Bearer token" and pasted the Token in its respective field.

When I click send, I get a success response with the user data.

In PHP, how can I do the same api call (using the id,email and token) inside a php function?

I tried this:

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "example.example.co.za/api/consumers/get?email=example@sample.com&id=567675675",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: */*",
    "Authorization: Bearer jhgukfytjfytdytfjgjyfytfjkugfyfdhtklhkugjf",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

return $response;
```

But when I view the page, instead of the user data, I see this:

[image]

How do I make the API call inside a function to get the same result that I have on postman in PHP?

Comment: A valid url needs a scheme like `https://`.

Comment: It's a redirect you are seeing. What's the actual URL look like?

Comment: @MarkusZeller `curl` is flexible, it tries to parse the URL similarly to the way browsers do in the address bar. So it will figure out that `example.example.co.za` is the domain and the scheme defaults to `http:`. The redirect is presumably the server try to switch it to `https:`

Comment: I combined @MarkusZeller comment with Bob's answer and now I am able to see the data,

Answer (score 3):

You need to follow the location

```
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true
```

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.curl-setopt.php

Answer (score 0):

Please find a proper CURL call here.

```
       $url = "https://example.example.co.za/api/consumers/get?id=567675675&email=example@sample.com";
       $curl = curl_init();

       // OPTIONS:
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
          'APIKEY: 111111111111111111111',
          'Content-Type: application/json',
       ));
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

       // EXECUTE:
       $result = curl_exec($curl);
       if(!$result){die("Connection Failure");}
       curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: what if I want the api key to be stored in a variable first? How would the full snippet look like?